# Does #MoreLoot Stack in Epic Clicker Journey?

Tags: steam, epic-clicker-journey

I have played for a little while now with two #MoreLoot in my inventory to see if there is any noticeable increase in loot drops as compared to only having one, but chests seem to drop the same amount of loot.

I found [this post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/414730/discussions/0/357284131792779034/) which included the similar stacking-related question about #KeyMeybe, but I did not find an answer to the question, **"Does #MoreLoot Stack in Epic Clicker Journey?"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**#MoreLoot does NOT stack.** Things that stack will appear multiple times on the side. Below is #EverybodyTastedIt, shown twice for two instances (stacking), while #MoreLoot only appears once (not stacking).

[image]